# Jquery accessing an array of divs with divs in them using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How would I access the 2nd div's inner divs text?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= $('.content').length - 1; i++) {
        $('.content').eq(i).click(function(e) {
                     $(this).hide();
            })
        }          
});
</script>

<div class='content'>
   <div class='text'>foo</div>
</div>

<div class='content'>
   <div class='text'>bar</div>
</div>

<div class='content'>
   <div class='text'>foobar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post some HTML, then we can see the structure of the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div.content:eq(1) .text").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector

```
$('div.content:eq(1) div.text').text(); //will return the actual text of the inner div

$('div.content:eq(1) div.text');  //will return the inner div with class text.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the posted jquery code is relevant to the question, but to access the text "bar", the 2nd div's inner div's text, you can do the following:

```
$(".content").eq(1).find(".text").text();
```

This says, get elements with the class of `content`, grab the 2nd one (`eq` is 0 based).  Then find within it, elements with the class `text` and get the `text` within the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Example -

```
$('div.content div.text').eq(1).html()
```

Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/HBZFQ/1/

Comment: You should remember that just class selection can prove to have poor performance on large HTML pages.  You should consider using `$('div.content div.text') instead of just the class selector, as it is more efficient.